# How can I easily use a 'floating' image to extend a background when a form's content increases?

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

I have a web-page with a section that contains a form with a background image, but when the form's contents are validated the form's length grows due to the validation messages displayed beneath the corresponding input fields so that the users can correct their entries.  Unfortunately, this causes the form's length to extend beyond the bottom of the form's background image, and looks odd.

The background image can't be repeated or stretched to 'fill-in' the larger form area.  Instead, I want to show the background image (hereafter referred to as the first image), which has beveled edges and a stippled pattern, with the bottom beveled edge clipped-off, and a second un-clipped copy of the same image (hereafter referred to as the second image) positioned so that it is covered by the first image, but with its bottom beveled edge 'poking-out' so that the combined images look to the user like a single image with four beveled edges.  This way when the form's length changes, more of the background image is revealed to fill-out the 'form-area'.

Because the same background image is used twice then both versions will use the same cached image, reducing storage space and load time.

In the demo, below, the first image is used for the form's background and a second image that floats below that.  The sliders and (+/-) buttons are used to add and remove lines from the 'form area' so that the background and floating images can be seen to adjust so that the expanding/contracting 'form area' still has a nice looking background behind it.

As I say, below, the demo provided, also below, doesn't quite work when more that 61 lines of text are added to the 'form area'.  What needs to happen is that the floating image that shows the bottom bevel needs to also expand so that the combined images can fill-up a 'form-area' of up to about 120 more lines.  Of course the larger the background image, the more expansion lines the 'form-area' can accommodate.

Update: I have a mostly working version that is almost right, in that when up to 61 lines of text are added to the 'form area' it looks fine with the background image expanding so it completely fills the form.  Beyond 61 lines, the background image splits with the bottom bevel separating from the main background image, leaving a gap. Use either the sliders or the (+/-) buttons to add and remove text from the 'form area'.

Here is the image I'm using as the background:

[image: Background Image.png]

And here is  the web-page that uses this image:

```js
const TOP = 0, RIGHT = 1, BOTTOM = 2, LEFT = 3, MARGINTOP = 4;

// Top range slider.
const moreText1            = document.querySelector( '#moreText1' );

// Top range slider value.
const moreTextValue1       = document.querySelector( '#moreTextValue1' );

// Bottom range slider.
const moreText2            = document.querySelector( '#moreText2' );

// Bottom range slider value.
const moreTextValue2       = document.querySelector( '#moreTextValue2' );

// Top number inputs.
const inputs               = document.querySelectorAll( 'input' );

const initial_top          = Number( inputs[ TOP ].value );
const initial_clientHeight = document.querySelector( '.bk-img' )
                                     .clientHeight;

const showClip             = document.querySelector( '#showClip' );
const img                  = document.querySelector( 'img' );

var   UNDEFINED;

showClip.innerText         = getImgClip();

function getImgClip() {
  var style     = img.getAttribute( 'style' );

  var styles, il, jl;

  if( style )

    style = style.nodeValue;

  else {

    style  = UNDEFINED;
    styles = document.querySelectorAll( 'style' );
    il     = styles.length;
    for( var i=0; ( ( i < il ) && ( style === UNDEFINED ) ); ++i ) {

      jl   = styles[ i ].sheet.rules.length;
      for( var j=0; j < jl; ++j )
        if( styles[ i ].sheet.rules[ j ].selectorText === 'img' ) {

          style = styles[ i ].sheet.rules[ j ].cssText;
          style = style.substring( style.indexOf( '{' ) + 1,
                                   style.indexOf( '}' ) - 1 ).trim();

          break;

        }

    }

  }

  return style;

}

function change( mode ) {
  var   top            = inputs[ TOP ].value;
  var   right          = inputs[ RIGHT ].value;
  var   bottom         = inputs[ BOTTOM ].value;
  var   left           = inputs[ LEFT ].value;
  var   marginTop      = inputs[ MARGINTOP ].value;
  var   new_top        = document
                        .querySelector( '.bk-img' )
                        .clientHeight +
                          initial_top -
                          initial_clientHeight;
  var   cycle          = ( ( mode !== UNKNOWN ) ? 2 : 1 );

  var   clip;

  do {

    if( mode !== true ) {

      clip             = 'rect( ' + top + 'px, ' +
                                    right  + 'px, ' +
                                    bottom + 'px, ' +
                                    left + 'px )';
      img.style.clip   = clip;

    }
    else {

      clip             = 'rect( ' + new_top + 'px, ' +
                                    right  + 'px, ' +
                                    bottom + 'px, ' +
                                    left + 'px )';
      img.style.clip   = clip;

    }

    if( marginTop !== '0' ) {

      img.style.marginTop = marginTop + 'px';

    }
    else {

      img.style.marginTop = '';

    }

    showClip.innerText = getImgClip();

    mode = UNKNOWN;
    --top;

  } while( cycle-- > 1 );

}
//  change();

function moreText_input( This ) {
  moreText1.value          =
  moreText1.toolTop        =
  moreTextValue1.innerText =
  moreText2.value          =
  moreText2.toolTop        =
  moreTextValue2.innerText = This.value;
}

function moreText_change( This ) {
  //
  // The buttons at the top and bottom of the page incrementally control
  // adding/removing/resetting the content of the text area with each click
  // of these buttons.  Because the action of these buttons is cumulative,
  // the count or amount of lines added/removed in the last call of this
  // function is needed by the current call in order to determine the new
  // number of lines to be put into the text area.  This value is stored in
  // the moreText_change.last_count function attribute.
  //
  // The effect of adding/removing/resetting the content of the text area is
  // to increase/decrease the size of the text area, thus causing more of
  // the background image to be visible, up to the size of the background
  // area.
  //
  // Note, the size of the text area is only determined by the text content
  // and the min_height style, not the background image, thus the bottom or
  // unseen part of the background image is cut-off.  The floating image of
  // the same image is used to 'complete' the background image by showing
  // the bottom bevel using the css clip function.  The only really works
  // when the background image doesn't looks 'odd' because the bevel part
  // doesn't match the background image as it is appended to the truncated
  // background image.
  //

  // The content area from which to add/remove text.
  var text       = document.getElementById( 'text' );

  // The amount of text rows to add/remove.
  var count      = Number( This.value );

  // Indicate add(+)/remove(-) or reset(0).
  var firstChar  = This.value.charAt( 0 );

  // Get the indicated add/remove/reset action.
  var sign       = ( ( firstChar === '-' )
                     ? '-'         // Negatively signed button was used.
                     : ( ( firstChar === '+' )
                         ? '+'     // Positively signed button was used.
                         : ( ( firstChar === '0' )
                             ? '0' // Reset button or range slider at 0 was used.
                             : '?' ) ) );  // The range slider was used.

  // Get the last_count value, if it exists.
  var last_count = ( ( moreText_change.last_count === undefined )
                     ? 1
                     : moreText_change.last_count );

  text.innerHTML = 'Hello World!'; // Reset the text area's content to one line.

  //
  // When sign is '?', then the range slider was used and its value was
  // greater than zero, set the text area to the number of lines specified
  // by count.
  //

  //
  // If the sign of the button control's value is plus(+), minus(-), or
  // reset(0), then change the text area's content by the amount of lines in
  // count.
  //
  // If the sign of the button control's value is a question mark(?), then
  // the range slider was used.
  //
  // Assign the updated number of text lines to count and the function
  // attribute, last_count, then add the lines to the text area.
  //

  if( sign !== '?' ) {

    if( ( count >= 0 ) && ( sign !== '-' ) ) {

      // This branch handles the plus(+) and reset(0) cases.

      // Count is 0 or a positive value.

      count = ( ( sign === '+' ) ? last_count + count : count );          

      // Keep count equal to or under the max range.

      count = Math.min( count, Number( moreText1.max ) );

    }
    else {

      //
      // This branch is similar to the above case, except that only the
      // minus(-) case is handled here.
      //

      // Count is a negative number.

      count = last_count + count;

      // If the new total is less than 0, set count to 0.

      count = Math.max( 0, count );

    }

  }

  for( var i=1; i < count; ++i )
    text.innerHTML += '<br />' + 'Hello World!';

  moreText_change.last_count   = ( count ? count : 1 );
  moreText1.value              =
  moreText2.value              = Math.max( 0, moreText_change.last_count );

//    change( true );

  showClip.innerText           = getImgClip();

}
```

```css
body { width: 893px; }
.vac { padding: 33px 0; }
.bk-img  {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBj4I.jpg");
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: white;
  min-height: 68px;
}
.area { background-color: lightgray; }
img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip: rect( 1080px, 893px, 1148px, 0px );
  margin-top: -1149px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <div style="display: none;">
    top:&nbsp;<input type="number" id="top"
                     onchange="change();" value=1080 />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    right:&nbsp;<input type="number" id="right"
                       onchange="change();" value=893 />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    bottom:&nbsp;<input type="number" id="bottom"
                        onchange="change();" value=1148 />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    left:&nbsp;<input type="number" id="top"
                      onchange="change();" value=0 /><br /><br />
    marginTop:&nbsp;<input type="number" id="margintop"
                           onchange="change();" value=-1149 />
  </div>
  More&nbsp;Text:&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative;  width: 134px;">
    <input type="range" id="moreText1"
           style="position: absolute; margin-top: -1px;"
           min="0" max="99" value="0"
           tooltip="0"
           oninput="moreText_input( this );"
           onchange="moreText_change( this );" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="moreTextValue1"
       style="display: inline-block; width: 19px;">0</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <div style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 10px;">
    <button value=-50
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">-50</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=-25
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">-25</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=-10
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">-10</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=-5
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">-5</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=-1
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">-1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button value=0
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">0</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=+1
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">+1</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=+5
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">+5</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=+10
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">+10</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=+25
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">+25</button>&nbsp;
    <button value=+50
            onclick="moreText_change( this );">+50</button>&nbsp;
  </div>
  <p id="showClip"></p>
</p>
<div class="area">
  <div class="vac"><h1>The background-image Property</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="bk-img">
  <div id="text"
       class="vac"
       style="position: relative; z-index: 100; text-align: center;">
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBj4I.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="area">
  <div class="vac">footer area</div>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
More&nbsp;Text:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 134px;">
  <input type="range" id="moreText2"
         style="position: absolute; margin-top: -1px;"
         min="0" max="99" value="0"
         tooltip="0"
         oninput="moreText_input( this );"
         onchange="moreText_change( this );" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="moreTextValue2"
     style="display: inline-block; width: 19px;">0</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button value=-50
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">-50</button>&nbsp;
<button value=-25
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">-25</button>&nbsp;
<button value=-10
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">-10</button>&nbsp;
<button value=-5
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">-5</button>&nbsp;
<button value=-1
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">-1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button value=0
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">0</button>&nbsp;
<button value=+1
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">+1</button>&nbsp;
<button value=+5
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">+5</button>&nbsp;
<button value=+10
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">+10</button>&nbsp;
<button value=+25
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">+25</button>&nbsp;
<button value=+50
        onclick="moreText_change( this );">+50</button>&nbsp;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd build the form in a way that showing the validation errors doesn't change the size, but given that's not what you're asking, can you create a codepen that contains the actual images you're using, and the inputs?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I don't have the image on a server that can be referenced by codepen.  The image is a rectangular png image where the horizontal is about 900px and the vertical is around 2000px, but when the for grows, it grows only in the vertical direction and by amounts depending on how many messages are displayed.

Comment: Just put it on imgur, then right-click it to copy its URL.

Comment: I found imgur, and created a new version of the page at codepen to use the image I posted at imgur, but the image doesn't show due to a cross-site cookie problem.  https://cdpn.io/howardb1/debug/wvBKpKZ/mVkbGDwjwgnM

Comment: About the messages. I want the messages right next to the fields that the user entered data into on the form, and I want to display all of the values that didn't pass validation. I don't like forms that only show one error at a time and place the messages away from the relevant field.

Comment: Here is the new image's link: https://imgur.com/a/eP4Lbp9

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/u8w4zkqo/ (it's just the pattern as image, everything else is CSS)

Comment: Chris, Wow, so simple -- Thanks!  I really like that the main work is all in the CSS. 
 However, I have one question -- I see that you removed the beveled edges from the image and then added them back using CSS, fine, but why did you use the before pseudo css rule?

Comment: You're right, that's not necessary; I somehow thought it would add the borders outside the pattern :) I fixed the fiddle

Comment: Thanks again.  I worked with your solution, and ultimately replaced the beveled borders created using css and broke the image into three parts, a small top-bevel-cap, a small bottom-bevel-cap, and a medium middle section that has left and right beveled borders.  I believe this slightly speeds things up because the side borders don't need to be generated.  However, if I needed to allow the form width to also grow, then I'd go with what you suggested because the managing side border caps would probably be more complex than just applying the side bevels with css, the way you did.

Comment: By the way, when I originally posted my image, I couldn't use it in CodePen version of my page, is there a trick that I need to use so I can do this?   I see that you're using js-fiddle, but I like CodePen because I can display the page in debug-mode and in Google Chrome's code-inspector, the page looks better because it isn't deep-down in an iframe, whereas in js-fiddle, I don't see a debug-mode, at lease in the free version, so the code-inspector shows a much more complex page.

Comment: After uploading the image on imgur, right-click it and select "Copy Image location". This will give you a direct image URL you can then use as you want. No trick, it's just that the URL that imgur provides is a link to a page that displays your image, not the direct link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version of this demo page that supports continuous expansion:

https://codepen.io/howardb1/full/wvBGKPP/full

```
All of the code can be seen in the above codepen.
```